# Facebook Ads API /adcreatives video error

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

My team and I have been crawling both the net and Facebook Docs for answers, but for some reason there are no valid answers to our question.

So we desperately hope for help from someone here

We are trying to create a video AD on facebook. Upload is done and we are at the step where we need to create the creative through /adcreatives endpoint.

Below is the body of the POST : 
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_[account_id]/adcreatives

```
 {
      "access_token": "token_that_is_valid",
      "object_story_spec": {
        "page_id": "valid_numeric_page_id",
        "video_data":{
          "image_url": "link_to_img",
            "video_id": "valid_numeric_video_id",
            "call_to_action" :{
                "type": "LEARN_MORE",
                "value":{
                    "link": "my_link",
                    "link_caption":"my_link_caption",
                    "link_description": "description"
                }
            }
       }

      },
      "name":"jjkkllkjljl"
    }
```

The response from facebook is rather worrying :

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 1487390,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Adcreative Create Failed",
        "error_user_msg": "The Adcreative Create Failed for the following reason: Oops, something went wrong. Please try again later",
        "fbtrace_id": "EVL6GYOOtYi"
    }
}
```

Also as an extra info, creating both non-video / image creatives and herafter ads is not an issue. Posting pre uploaded videos to a page is NOT an issue. All access rights has been given to the Facebook APP.

Thank you for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem with Python.
To fix it you shouldn't use video_id from admin panel.[screenshot from admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRCVN.png)

You should upload video and get video_id from API.
Example Python code:

`video = AdVideo(parent_id=ad_account_id)
 video[AdVideo.Field.filepath] = 'test.mp4'
 video.remote_create()
 video_id_for_creative=video.get_id()`

Answer (score 0):

`link description` is not a valid parameter in the `call_to_action` value: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative-link-data-call-to-action-value/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however removing the parameter still causes same error response :

{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 1487390,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "Adcreative Create Failed",
        "error_user_msg": "The Adcreative Create Failed for the following reason: Oops, something went wrong. Please try again later",
        "fbtrace_id": "HCBkspNSpM5"
    }
}

Comment: Yes. also tried v2.9 . Do you have a working POST example ?

Comment: I actually also just got the same error. You should submit a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Thanks, ive reported the bug to facebook. Lets see what happens

Comment: @user553869 Did you get response from Facebook when you reported this bug ?  I am facing the same error for similar video data thing.